# Set up KaiOS Environment on Mac OS high Sierra

Tags: macos, kaios

I followed the [KaiOS](https://developer.kaiostech.com/environment-setup) documentation to set up environment for KaiOS app development but the instructions there provided is only for Debian/unix system most of command is not working because lack of `apt` in mac.

How should I set up KaiOS development environment for Mac OS High Sierra?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get things working without going through the steps listed on the site, but skipping straight ahead to install the simulator:

https://developer.kaiostech.com/simulator

Mind you, this isn't running on an actual device (yet), but just the simulator itself.

Comment: The URL is a dead link

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Mac user but if you want WebIDE to sideload and debug apps, there are many alternatives you've got like a version of Firefox older than 59. If you can't find binaries, you can try compiling.